# How to Loop Through Firebase JSON in React

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, loops, jsx

I have the following JSON Data coming out of Firebase RTDB:

```
{"\"1\"":{"itemDescription":"This is a description of the item.","itemName":"Item Name","itemValue":{"costAmount":200,"costType":"dol"}},
"\"2\"":{"itemDescription":"This is an item description.","itemName":"Item Name 2","itemValue":{"costAmount":500,"costType":"dol"}}}
and so on...
```

The data is parsed (json.parse) and stored a variable called parsedJSONData in `state`.

I've tried looping through it using other recommendations on this site and others, such as:

```js
    this.state.parsedJSONData.map(json => {
      <div className="item">
        <p>Item: {json.itemName}</p>
      </div>;
    });
```

And I'm getting errors like the below:

Line 68:  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions

Any tips on what I can do? I know the data is parsed correctly, because if I output the contents of the parsedJsonData to the console, I can see the data is structured correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Try Using `forEach()` instead of `map()`

Comment: Hi, I get the error: TypeError: this.state.parsedJSONData.forEach is not a function
 if I do this.

Answer (score 0):

You are not returning anything inside of your `map()`. [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) you can look at the different ways to return values from an arrow function, but in short, data will be returned in these two forms:

1. `json => json.itemName`
2. `json => {return json.itemName;}`

Drop the `{}` inside of your map or throw a `return` inside like so:

```
    this.state.parsedJSONData.map(({itemName}) => 
      <div className="item">
        <p>Item: {itemName}</p>
      </div>
    );
```

or

```
    this.state.parsedJSONData.map(({itemName}) => {
      return <div className="item">
        <p>Item: {itemName}</p>
      </div>;
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! However, when I do exactly what you have stated I get: TypeError: this.state.parsedJSONData.map is not a function

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I have tried this and it works for the your json Data.

```
render() {
   var tempData = [];
   const theDataWeHave = this.state.parsedJSONData;
   for(var row in theDataWeHave){
     var rowEntry = theDataWeHave[row];
     tempData.push(rowEntry);
   }

var renderVariable = tempData.map(function(item,index) {
    return ( <RenderThisComponent key={index} item={item}/> )
})

}

return(
   //your code for other stuff
   {renderVariable}  //Place this where you want to render the component
)
```

The component you want to render will be a separate functional component with props passed to it.
You can write in the same file or you can write in separate file and import+export
.I have done in the same file so it do not need to be exported or imported.

```
const RenderThisComponent = (props) => (
   <div className="item">
      <p>Item: {props.item.itemName}</p>
    </div>
)
```

Comment: Actually the problem is your json data coming from Firebase RTDB. It is assigning the row number for your data as string i.e ` "\"1\"" ` is `"1"` and not `1`. So what i actually did was - converting your json data into correct format and then i mapped it to render the component.